# How does moodle store the response of a user

Tags: moodle

I am trying to build my own application in Java which displays the option chosen by the user for a question in a quiz. Which database table stores that information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Schema and ERD for quiz here: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_database_structure or more precisely http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Question_database_structure

The answers are stored in questions_answers